# plugins in jquery together with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm new with angular and I've read that it wasn't a good practice use it together with jQuery.

There are lots of cool plugins developed in jQuery and it's not possible to get them in angular... you should build them for your own in angular if you want to get the same behavior.

For instance, you can find many admin dashboard templates in jQuery but just a few in angular.

My question is if it's really necessary to use angular in something built in jQuery by a third party or you can start your app in angular and when you need some plugin built in jQuery... just use it to avoid spending time building the same plugin in angular... I'd like to know how to solve this kind of situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From AngularJS [FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

Comment: Thanks I know you can use jquery and angular at the same time my question was if it was a good practise

Comment: @PabloPoliti Then your question is off-topic and should be closed :(